# How to get value from input without submitting and search it from datalist

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, xampp

```
> This Is My HTML CODE

<label>Person</label>
<input name="PersonID" type="text" id="PersonID">

<label>Car Plate Number</label>
<input name="PersonsCarPlateNumber" list="PersonsCarPlateNumber" type="text" />

> This is My PHP CODE

<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "PersonWithCars");
$result = $conn->query("SELECT CarPlateNumber FROM Persons WHERE ID = '***PERSONID***' ");
?>

> This Is My Data List Where The Search For Persons Car

<datalist id=PersonsCarPlateNumber>
<?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()):?>
<?php unset($CarPlateNumber);
$CarPlateNumber = $row['CarPlateNumber'];?>
<option value="<?php echo $CarPlateNumber?>"></option>
<?php endwhile;?>
</datalist>
```

1. need help sorry my code is messed up just a beginner here learning

   - PersonID,PersonsCarPlateNumber

Comment: It can be achieved via ajax.

Comment: how master can u give me some piece of code i can use as reference?

Comment: https://openenergymonitor.org/forum-archive/node/107.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- date picker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>

<!-- 2 decimal places -->
<input onchange='fixit(this)'>
<script>
  function fixit( obj ) {
    obj.value = parseFloat( obj.value ).toFixed( 2 )
  }
</script>

<!-- query -->
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","employeesystem");

$checkid = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE studid = '$studid'";
$result = $conn->query($checkid);


/*query with rows*/
$checkid = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE studid = '$studid'";
$result = $conn->query($checkid);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $stud = $row['studname'];
    }
}

?>
<!-- for table row display -->
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>empid</th>
    <th>name</th> 
    <th colspan="3">combine</th>
  </tr>
  <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):?>
  <tr>
    <td><center><?php echo $row['studid'];?></center></td>
    <td><center><a href="viewstud.php?studid=<?php echo $row['studid'];?>">view</a></center></td>
  </tr>
  <?php endwhile;?>
</table>
```